# What is the inverse Laplace of $(e^{-sx/c})(-f_0/s^3)$

Tags: laplace-transform, inverse-laplace

Where $c$ and $f_0$ are constants. I know it should be of the form $H(t-a)f(t-a)$ but I got lost a bit

Comment: The variable is $s$ ?  So $x$ is also a constant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $f_0,x,c$ are constants and $x,c>0$, Maple says
$$
{\rm invlaplace} \left( {\frac {-f_0}{{s}^{3}}{{\rm e}^{-{
sx/c}}}},s,t \right) =
-{\frac {f_0\, \left( ct-x \right) ^{2}}{2{c}^{2}}
H\left( t-{\frac {x}{c}} \right) }
$$
Here $H$ is the [Heaviside step function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function)